# Anyone tried to bond merchandise in Qatar airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, qatar-airways, qatar, doha

Has anyone tried bonding hand carried merchandise into Qatar for one day stop over? I’ve looked in Hamad airport website if they have that service but couldn’t find any information . I will be travelling to Qatar with precious stones for a one day stop over, I need to know if I could leave them at customs and pick up when I depart or will I be able to just carry them outside.

Answer (score 2):

What I know for sure,

- The Doha airport has no locker facility for in-transit passengers.
- If the stones you have are in the form of some Jewelry and you are wearing it, then you can carry with you outside the airport.
- If you can not carry them, book the lounge which provides the locker facility. There are lounges at Doha airport which provides the safe locker services. (Charges may apply extra)
- You can also book a good transit hotel room which has locker inside.

Make sure,

- You must carry proofs of those stones/Jewelry belongs to you. 
  -If customs finds those stones, then you should have enough evidence to show that they are not for sale.
- Confirm the amount of jewelry or stones you can carry with you. Every country has specific rules when it comes to GOLD and Diamonds.

For more details read this [Security and Custom @ Doha Airport](https://dohahamadairport.com/airport-guide/at-the-airport/security-customs)

My suggestion,

> Carrying highly valuable items during travel is always risky. That too when you are traveling to a unknown country. try to minimize the risk by keeping all paperwork needed and follow the rules and law of that specific country.

Hope this helps.